F1 Telemetry on Server
"I want to get the telemetry data from the F1 2023 game for which I am using the package @racehub-io/f1-telemetry-client to get these. But there's nothing showing in the console."

const { F1TelemetryClient, constants } = require('f1-telemetry-client');
const { PACKETS } = constants;

/*
*   'port' is optional, defaults to 20777
*   'bigintEnabled' is optional, setting it to false makes the parser skip bigint values,
*                   defaults to true
*   'forwardAddresses' is optional, it's an array of Address objects to forward unparsed telemetry to. each address object is comprised of a port and an optional ip address
*                   defaults to undefined
*   'skipParsing' is optional, setting it to true will make the client not parse and emit content. You can consume telemetry data using forwardAddresses instead.
*                   defaults to false
*/
const client = new F1TelemetryClient({ port: 20777 });
client.on(PACKETS.event, (data) => {
    console.log("Event-Daten empfangen");
    try {
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Fehler beim Verarbeiten der Daten: ", error);
    }
});
client.on(PACKETS.motion, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.carSetups, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.lapData, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.session, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.participants, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.carTelemetry, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.carStatus, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.finalClassification, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.lobbyInfo, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.carDamage, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.sessionHistory, console.log);
client.on(PACKETS.tyreSets, console.log);

// to start listening:
client.start();

